# How to get the URL of an iOS application before it is accepted by Apple?

Tags: ios, xcode, admob, app-store-connect

First of all, I know that there are a lot of posts related to my question but my situation is a bit different.

Actually I use Admob in my application to present ads, but my approval status is set to "review required" because I've not add my App's URL on AppStore yet.

I tried to go to : App Store Connect > My apps > App concerned > App information > View in the app store. I've copied the URL from my browser and add it to Admob but here is the message I get from Admob when I search my app with this URL :

> Can't find your application? Check its information on the download platform and try again.

And this makes sense as the application is not yet published on the AppStore. The problem is that the app cannot be accepted if the ads do not work.

Can anyone suggest a solution ?

Thank you for your attention !

Comment: Have you had your app rejected because the ads have failed to load? Your app should handle situations in which ads can't be loaded anyway, like when the user has no internet connection.

Comment: Yes my application displays a pop up indicating that the add could not be loaded. However, Apple can't test some features because of this and therefore rejects my application.

Comment: It probably isn't appropriate to show a pop up or prevent the app from running because ads can't be loaded.  Your app should handle the situation gracefully and carry on regardless. If you do want to annoy your users then you can release an update later once your first version has been approved.

Comment: Why is it not appropriate to display a pop-up? It is a rewarded ad that the user decides to launch. That's why ads don't bother users in the application. 
Nevertheless I think the only solution is to offer an alternative that allows the verification team to test the application completely without the use of ads that will work when the application is launched.

Answer (score 0):

First of All, the sentence below is not true:

> The problem is that the app cannot be accepted if the ads do not work.

Apple will accept the app if it has no Ads without any problems.

**BUT** if you really really need an Ad to appear, you can use in house ads until the app get published.

in house Ads will appear even if your app is not published yet.